# Exercise 1.5.1 in Guillemin and Pollack

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Suppose that $A: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear map and $V$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Check that $A$ is transversal to $V$ means just $A(\mathbb{R}^k) + V = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Could anyone give me a hint on how to prove it?

Comment: Here you mean *direct sum* ($A(\Bbb R^k)\oplus V=\Bbb R^n$), don't you? Also, can you cite here how is 'transversal' defined. It should easily follow from the definition..

Comment: No I do not mean direct sum @Berci

Comment: You need to view $A$ as a smooth map and consider its differential. What is the differential of a linear map? What is the tangent space at a point in a vector space?

Comment: The differential of a linear map is the linear map itself and the tangent space at a point in a vector space is the vector space itself @Max

Comment: Ok, so take a look at the definition of transverse on page 28...

Comment: @Berci for the record, 'transverse' is meant to imply 'intersect in a submanifold' rather than 'intersect in a point.' For example, a generic pair of 2-planes in 3-space should intersect 'transversely.' So you want sum rather than direct sum.